# how to using dynamic dblink oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

how to using dynamic dblink en oracle:

```
create PROCEDURE db_example
    IS
            
    v_DB_TOTAL_SIZE_KB NUMBER :=0;
    v_DB_USED_SIZE_KB NUMBER :=0;
    v_DB_FREE_SIZE_KB NUMBER :=0;
            
    CURSOR c_DB_LINK_MSS is SELECT '@' || DB_LINK NAME FROM dba_db_links
    BEGIN
        FOR v_DB_LINK_NAME in c_DB_LINK_MSS
        LOOP
          BEGIN
            CURSOR c_databases IS SELECT "name" db_name, CAST( ( SUM("size") * 8192 ) /1024 / 102
             AS DECIMAL(15,2)) AS db_size
                      FROM "sys"."master_files" || v_DB_LINK_NAME || group by "name";
        
                BEGIN

              
               FOR r_database IN c_databases LOOP
               -- insert in table
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('La base de datos ' || r_database.db_name || ' size ' || v_db_size );

              END LOOP;
               END IF;
       END LOOP;
    END;
END;`
```

select al dblink and insert db_size in oracle db for view en oracle apex monitor

Comment: You need dynamic sql for such things. So you can generate a sql query and store in variable and then use `execute immediate your_variable_with_sql into ...`